# Fast way to discretize normal distribution in Python

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution

I try to optimize this code, to discretize the cdf of the normal distribution (with n points, and delta beetween two points equal to 10**c):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
def norm_disc(m, s, n, c):
    cdf = norm(m, s).cdf
    bornes = np.arange(-0.5, n) * 10 ** c
    L = np.diff(cdf(bornes))
    L[0] += cdf(bornes[0])
    L[-1] += 1 - cdf(bornes[-1])
    return L
```

Is there anyway to make it faster?

Comment: Do you mean get an histogram of count or density with a bin fixed bin size? What is the problem you are facing? What would be the expected result? How fast? What resolution?

Comment: Just want a list which represents the discretization of the normal distribution. My code work but i want it faster if possible, because I call this function many time

Comment: That code seems as vectorized as it can be. Maybe there are some % to gain with other methods, other implementatins of `cdf`. But not factors 10,100 or 1000 as we often see here with non vectorized code. The real question is "can you avoid to call it many times"? Can you, for example, vectorize also those many times

Answer (score 0):

I observed a factor of ~70 by replacing `norm.cdf` with `scipy.special.ndtr`. SciPy distributions have a lot of overhead, but `special.ndtr` just computes the CDF of the standard normal distribution. We can transform the input to get the correct result for any shifted/scaled normal distribution.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.special import ndtr

def norm_disc1(m, s, n, c):
    cdf = norm(m, s).cdf
    bornes = np.arange(-0.5, n) * 10 ** c
    L = np.diff(cdf(bornes))
    L[0] += cdf(bornes[0])
    L[-1] += 1 - cdf(bornes[-1])
    return L

def norm_disc2(m, s, n, c):
    cdf = lambda x: ndtr((x-m)/s)
    bornes = np.arange(-0.5, n) * 10 ** c
    L = np.diff(cdf(bornes))
    L[0] += cdf(bornes[0])
    L[-1] += 1 - cdf(bornes[-1])
    return L

args = 1, 2, 100, 1
np.testing.assert_equal(norm_disc1(*args), norm_disc2(*args))
%timeit norm_disc1(*args)
# 1.59 ms ± 297 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit norm_disc2(*args)
# 22.5 µs ± 2.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```